Is it possible to export Animoji to a file and preserve the transparent, alpha layer background?
I've created a Animoji (video version of an emoji) on my iPhone and I noticed that it appears to have a transparent, alpha background. I would like to save this Animoji with its transparent background and transfer it to my Mac for further use.
I've seen another post here that opening and saving it in Quicktime on a mac makes it possible to keep the transparency, but it turned to alpha channel into a static black background after saving.

Welcome to Ask Different.  Please link to your research so a) others can learn what to look for and b) we can answer you it if we have a different search term.  I believe your question is covered here and there is an answer that should be considered

@bmike thank you for your answer! I have the exact same problem as the OP in the topic which you highlighted. I already tried the solution provided there, but it doesn't works (I specified that in my initial post). Maybe it was working earlier, but with Sonoma 14.5 and Quicktime 10.5 the background is black and not transparent after opening and saving it using Quicktime.

If you would be kind enough to edit in your post exactly those details, people will be less likely to close it as a duplicate of the previous iteration. Great confirmation on the setup.
